# Issue in understanding routing in VLSI CAD

Tags: routing, vlsi, cad

I have chosen to undertake VLSI CAD as a part of my electronics degree and I came across this statement (Source : Naveed Sherwani, Algorithms for VLSI Physical Design Automation, 3rd edition , Chapter 8. Global Routing , Page 251) :

[image: the statement]

I had an issue in understanding as to why channels and 2d switchboxes are routed first. I cannot comprehend what it is trying to convey.

Comment: @VoltageSpike I did not understand what that statement even implied (why are 2d and channel routed first)